# what is the easiest way to generate Add,edit and delete of a table in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, generated-code

I always code add, edit and delete pages from scratch "I mean copy paste :)" for my tables, but man, it's boring and time consuming. isn't there an easy way to generate those pages and manipulate the configurations of their forms to suit my projects' needs?
I use ASP.net with C#, I've tried ASP.netMaker but the generated code is hard to read and difficult to manipulate and use out of its layout.

Answer (score 0):

You must check ASP.Net Dynamic Data it allows to do what you need. Here is a good [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535665.aspx) to achieve what you need very quickly